# Issuer and Audience of Jwt Token in ASP Dot Net Web Api Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

what are the values that can be given to Issuer and Audience in Jwt

> appsettings.json

```
"Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "",
    "Audience": "", 
    "Key": ""
  },
```

> Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))

                };
            });
```

1.What value should I enter to the Issuer and Audience field?
2.Is it necessary to enter values to the fields?
3.I had done the project without entering any values to the above mentioned fields but I can,t acess the API endpoints with [Authentication] attribute.Where should be the error?

I am working on ASP .Net Core 6 Web API

Answer (score 0):

You may need a `options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";`

For my project, the following minimize configuration code works:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                     .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = false

    };
});
```

You can decode your token at https://jwt.io/ .I use identity server 4 "clientCredential Flow" to generate token(at port:5001). For my token it's like
[image]
The following setting also works

```
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "https://localhost:5001/resources",
```

I tried your other configurations, but there is no impact.